# Lisp evaluation using cond in a defun

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Lisp noob here.

```
CL-USER> (defun my-if (a b c)
           (cond (a b)
                 (t c)))

CL-USER> (my-if t (print 1) (print 2))
1
2
1
```

I didn't expect to get the 2, because the second clause in the `cond` shouldn't get evaluated if the first is true:

```
CL-USER> (cond (t (print 1))
               (t (print 2)))
1
1
```

Is this why we need macros, or am I making some other mistake?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Arguments of functions in Common Lisp are evaluated before getting into function. When `(print 1)` is evaluated it prints `1` and returns `1`. When `(print 2)` is evaluated it prints `2` and returns `2`. `1` and `2` go into the function. And it returns `1` as an answer.

To do what you want to do, you need to write a macro:

```
CL-USER> (defmacro my-if (a b c)
           `(cond (,a ,b)
                  (t  ,c)))
MY-IF
CL-USER> (my-if t (print 1) (print 2))

1 
1
```

Comment: Note that this isn't any different than the behavior in other languages that might be familiar.  E.g., in C or Java -like languages, with a definition like `void my_if(boolean x, type then, type else) { if( x ) { return then; } else { return else; } }`, in a call `my_if( true, print(1), print(2) );` you'd see both 1 and 2 printed.

Answer (score 7):

Since the arguments to the function all get evaluated, you need to delay/force the evaluation:

```
CL-USER 35 > (defun my-if (condition then-thunk else-thunk)
               (cond (condition (funcall then-thunk))
                     (t         (funcall else-thunk))))
MY-IF

CL-USER 36 > (my-if t
                    (lambda () (print 1))
                    (lambda () (print 2)))

1
1

CL-USER 37 > (my-if nil
                    (lambda () (print 1))
                    (lambda () (print 2)))

2
2
```

Comment: Thanks Rainer. Macros is what I was after but this is also interesting and enlightening